# How to store filename and extracted content in hash?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am having many log files where it will have Code count.

I wanted to read the file and fetch the code count from it then store that in hash table like follows

fileName[without extension] = Codecount

For ex:

Comp1 = 65652
Comp2 = 54654

I have fetched the code count by following way and store it in array.

```
$Totallinesver2=@()
$Count=@()

      $Totallinesver2+=Get-ChildItem -Path $CCountFolder -Recurse | Foreach { Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-string -simplematch "Total Lines (version 2)" }`

    Foreach ( $line in $Totallinesver2) { $Count+= $($line -replace "Total Lines \(version 2\)        : ","" ).Trim()}
```

By doing above way i am not able to process both codecount and filename in single array. If it is stored in hash table , it would be easier. How to read the filename in Key and store code count in value ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$Count=@{}

  Get-ChildItem -Path $CCountFolder -Recurse |
   Foreach {
    $line_string = select-string $_.fullname -simplematch -pattern "Total Lines (version 2)" -list
    $lines = ($line_string.line -replace "Total Lines \(version 2\)        : ","" ).Trim()
    $count[$_.name] = $lines
    }

    $count
```

Comment: Compilation issues buddy. Missing closing '}' in statement block.

Comment: Edited.  Parens out of balance.

Comment: This approach did not work. It throws errors. "Cannot find path 'E:\Myfolder\Total Lines (version 2)' because it does not exist" I think you are not reading the content from file. no where it is mentioned. Can you update the answer accordingly

Comment: Try that.  Select-string reads the contents of files.  See get-help select-string -full.